# 'module' object has no attribute 'FunctionSet'

Tags: python

Running this code

```
 model = chainer.FunctionSet(conv1=F.Convolution2D(3,100,3, pad=1), 
         bn1   = F.BatchNormalization(100),
         conv2=F.Convolution2D(100,100,3, pad=1),
```

throws

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FunctionSet'

What could be my the Problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `chainer.FunctionSet` might have been removed
http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/upgrade.html

Use `Use Chain` or `ChainList` instead

Comment: ill check it !1